# Circuit Breaker with gRPC

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, circuit-breaker

In a `REST` service adding a circuit breaker with `hystrix`, I could do the following:

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "getBackupResult")
@GetMapping(value = "/result")
public ResponseEntity<ResultDto> getResult(@RequestParam("request") String someRequest) {

    ResultDto resultDto = service.parserRequest(someRequest);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(resultDto, HttpStatus.OK);
}

public ResponseEntity<ResultDto> getBackupResult(@RequestParam("request") String someRequest) {

    ResultDto resultDto = new ResultDto();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(resultDto, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Is there something similar I can do for the `gRPC` call?

```
public void parseRequest(ParseRequest request, StreamObserver<ParseResponse> responseObserver) {
    try {
        ParseResponse parseResponse  = service.parseRequest(request.getSomeRequest());

        responseObserver.onNext(parseResponse);
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Failed to execute parse request.", e);
        responseObserver.onError(new StatusException(Status.INTERNAL));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by implementing the circuit-breaker on my client. I used the [sentinel library](https://github.com/alibaba/Sentinel)

To react on exceptions ratio for example I added this rule:

```
    private static final String KEY = "callGRPC";

    private void callGRPC(List<String> userAgents) {
        initDegradeRule();
        ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(grpcHost, grpcPort).usePlaintext()
                                                      .build();
        for (String userAgent : userAgents) {
            Entry entry = null;
            try {
                entry = SphU.entry(KEY);
                UserAgentServiceGrpc.UserAgentServiceBlockingStub stub
                        = UserAgentServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
                UserAgentParseRequest request = UserAgentRequest.newBuilder().setUserAgent(userAgent).build();
                UserAgentResponse userAgentResponse = stub.getUserAgentDetails(request);
            } catch (BlockException e) {
                logger.error("Circuit-breaker is on and the call has been blocked");
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                logger.error("Exception was thrown", t);
            } finally {
                if (entry != null) {
                    entry.exit();
                }
            }
        }
        channel.shutdown();
    }

    private void initDegradeRule() {
        List<DegradeRule> rules = new ArrayList<DegradeRule>();
        DegradeRule rule = new DegradeRule();
        rule.setResource(KEY);
        rule.setCount(0.5);
        rule.setGrade(RuleConstant.DEGRADE_GRADE_EXCEPTION_RATIO);
        rule.setTimeWindow(60);
        rules.add(rule);
        DegradeRuleManager.loadRules(rules);
    }
```